# Array with nested slashes and parenthesis

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, arrays

I am trying to TeX the following schematic:

[image]

using some fiddling around with `multirow`s. However, everything's messed up, so I suppose there must be a more elegant way. How? So far, my attempts using `blkarray` also do not work out quite well…

Comment: What is a matrix?

Comment: @Sebastiano This is matrix https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vb6bA4J1Gbg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proposal using a combination of `array` and `matrix`. I've reduced the vertical space between lines using, for example, `[-1.3em]`. Also reduced the space between the contents and large outside brackets using `\mkern-8mu`, for example. You can change these numbers as you see fit. Adjustments to the column separation can be made using `\arraycolsep`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[ \arraycolsep=3pt
\left(\mkern-8mu 
\begin{array}{cccc}
& & & \begin{matrix} a\\b \end{matrix} \\[-1.3em]
& & \left( \begin{matrix} e\\f \end{matrix} \middle/ \begin{matrix} c\\d \end{matrix} \right) & \\[-1em]
& g & & \\[-1.3em]
\left( \begin{matrix} j\\k \end{matrix} \middle/ \begin{matrix} h\\i \end{matrix} \right) & & &
\end{array}
\mkern-3mu\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is really cool! I think it is even a bit handier if one puts the lonesome $g$ into a dummy `matrix`. Did you get the 1.3em just by trying, or is there a deeper reason?

Comment: No deep reason. I started off by putting `[-1em]` after each line break. And just adjusted them from there.

Comment: By the way, I'm curious, what does the word solidusses mean??

Comment: Unicode uses the name solidus it to refer to a slash. Since I am unaware of Latin, I do not know the proper plural form. ~~Solidūs?~~ Solidi, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solidus_(coin))